Monitor detected on ubuntu but monitor is saying no signal
I’m experiencing an issue with my dual external monitor setup (Dell 34" and Dell 27") connected to a Dell XPS running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. This setup has been working perfectly for a few months, but after installing some recommended Ubuntu updates this morning and rebooting, the 27" monitor stopped displaying.
Here’s what’s happening:

Only the 34" monitor displays anything. The 27" monitor is detected in the display settings, but it shows "No Signal." on the monitor.
Every 10 seconds or so the monitor will say it's trying to find a signal as if it knows something is connected to it. It will go to sleep after a few tries, but when I move the mouse or touch a key it tries to look for a signal again.
I’ve tried using another identical Dell 27" monitor, but it also doesn’t work. It seems like my system is suddenly incompatible with 27" displays.

What I’ve tried so far:

Verified that the affected monitor and cable work on other devices.
Rearranged cables and ports.
Created a backup of the monitors.xml file and rebooted (mv ~/.config/monitors.xml ~/.config/monitors.xml.bak).
Reset GNOME Display settings (dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/).
Installed the latest Intel graphics driver (xserver-xorg-video-intel).

I’m at a loss for what to do next. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Not an Ubuntu guy (OpenSUSE with KDE), but you might check if you have ddcutil installed.
It's a program that controls various functions involving communcations with the monitor. It handles things like brightness control, resolution changes, etc. I had to disable it for my machine, because it kept restarting my TV/monitor (old Samsung).
You can try ddcutil detect to see if it's detecting properly. If it's not, you might try disabling ddcutil through its config file withsystemctl --user edit plasma-powerdevil.service.
Here's a sample with the option to disable libddcutil -
[Service]

Environment="POWERDEVIL_NO_DDCUTIL=1"

Reboot, and see if GNOME recognizes your monitors properly. You may lose your software brightness functionality using this method.
To revert back to the previous behavior, you can delete the override file at "/home/$USER/.config/systemd/user/plasma(or gnome)-powerdevil.service.d/override.conf"
My power issue was due to ddcutil not recognizing my monitor. You might have a similar issue -
https://discuss.kde.org/t/monitor-powers-off-and-on-after-every-login/16610
Configuring libddcutil for Ubuntu is covered here.  - https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ddcutil.1.html

Had the same issue, plugging or unplugging the monitor didn't work properly. ddcutil was installed indeed. After running ddcutil detect the external monitor wasn't listed (although it was listed in Ubuntu Settings -> Displays). But after that, unplugging & plugging brought the external monitor to life (showing the Desktop instead of the message "No signal detected"). Thank you for the hint!
